# addEventListner activating for no reason?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some addEventListener's on `<td>` elements and as soon as i run the .html they 5 out of the 9 activate without me clicking on them. I am using jquery and the normalize.css file.

JAVASCRIPT

```
window.onload = function(){
    var turn = 1;
    document.title = "First Player";
    var coolDown = 'False';
    var Oone, Otwo, Othree, Ofour, Ofive, Osix, Oseven, Oeight, Onine, Xone, Xtwo, Xthree, Xfour, Xfive, Xsix, Xseven, Xeight, Xnine
    var OGridArray = [Oone, Otwo]
    var makeScreen = function(){
        var height = $(window).height();
        var width = $(window).width();
        $('#screen').height(height);
        $('#screen').width(height);
        var extraSpace = width - height;
        var halfOfExtraSpace = extraSpace / 2;
        $('#screen').css("left", halfOfExtraSpace);
    };

    var drawImage = function(section){
        if (turn == 1){
            if (coolDown == 'False'){
                alert(Oone) //Debugging stuff :p
                alert(Otwo)
                alert(Othree)
                alert(Ofour)
                alert(Ofive)
                alert(Osix)
                alert(Oseven)
                alert(Oeight)
                alert(Onine)
                OGridArray = [Oone, Otwo, Othree, Ofour, Ofive, Osix, Oseven, Oeight, Onine]
                if (OGridArray.indexOf('O' + section) == -1){
                    drawCircle(section);
                    turn = 2;
                    document.title = "Second Player";
                    coolDown = 'True';
                };              
            };
        };
        if (turn == 2){
            if (coolDown == 'False'){
                drawCross(section);
                turn = 1;
                document.title = "First Player";
                coolDown = 'True';
            };
        };
        coolDown = 'False';
    };
    var drawCircle = function(section){  
        alert('circle red')
        $('#' + section).css("background-color", "red")
        if ('O' + section == "Oone"){
            Oone = "Oone"
        };
        if ('O' + section == "Otwo"){
            Otwo = "Otwo"
        };
        if ('O' + section == "Othree"){
            Othree = "Othree"
        };
        if ('O' + section == "Ofour"){
            Ofour = "Ofour"
        };
        if ('O' + section == "Ofive"){
            Ofive = "Ofive"
        };
        if ('O' + section == "Osix"){
        Osix = "Osix"
        };
        if ('O' + section == "Oseven"){
            Oseven = "Oseven"
        };
        if ('O' + section == "Oeight"){
            Oeight = "Oeight"
        };
        if ('O' + section == "Onine"){
            Onine = "Onine"
        };


    };
    var drawCross = function(section){
        alert('cross blue')
    };
    makeScreen();
    var one = document.getElementById('one');
    one.addEventListener('click', drawImage('one'));
    var two = document.getElementById('two');
    two.addEventListener('click', drawImage('two'));
    var three = document.getElementById('three');
    three.addEventListener('click', drawImage('three'));
    var four = document.getElementById('four');
    four.addEventListener('click', drawImage('four'));
    var five = document.getElementById('five');
    five.addEventListener('click', drawImage('five'));
    var six = document.getElementById('six');
    six.addEventListener('click', drawImage('six'));
    var seven = document.getElementById('seven');
    seven.addEventListener('click', drawImage('seven'));
    var eight = document.getElementById('eight');
    eight.addEventListener('click', drawImage('eight'));
    var nine = document.getElementById('nine');
    nine.addEventListener('click', drawImage('nine'));

};
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
        <title>JavaScript Interaction Test.</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="screen">
            <tr>
                <td id="one"></td>
                <td id="two"></td>
                <td id="three"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="four"></td>
                <td id="five"></td>
                <td id="six"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="seven"></td>
                <td id="eight"></td>
                <td id="nine"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Before commenting / voting, please keep in mind i am still learning javascript and i dont know quite a few things that other people may find easy and basic.

Thank you for your time.

PS: this is an image of what i am seeing:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the function is called right away is because you addded parentheses, which calls the function, you want to just reference it

```
one.addEventListener('click', drawImage);
```

that means no arguments, but you can use an anonymous function

```
one.addEventListener('click', function() {
    drawImage('one')
});
```

or use `this.id` instead inside the `drawImage` function, it's seems like that should be the same thing.

The real question is perhaps why you're not using jQuery

```
$('#screen tr td').on('click', function() {
    drawImage(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! sorry it took me a long time to reply... My computer had a breakdown... But thank you i've just tested this and it works :)